# Communications across AppDomains

Tags: .net, appdomain

Is there a way to share an interface accross AppDomain boundaries? That is, can I reference an instance within another AppDomain within my process using a shared interface? I know one can use WCF with named pipes, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct (and simpler) way to communicate in an object oriented way.

Comment: You are looking for good ol' .NET Remoting.

Comment: You don't need full blown remoting if it's the same process. Just a MarshalByRef object and AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap will do the trick (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a second AppDomain and pass a MarshalByRef object (presumably that inherits your interface) across the AppDomain boundary. Simple example is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx

So in the example:

```
    AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");
    Worker remoteWorker = (Worker) ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
        "Worker");
```

remoteWorker is an in instance in "New domain". The variable remoteWorker in the calling domain is actually a TransparentProxy which marshals the calls to the real instance in the other app domain.

Comment: AppDomains do not share memory space though, do they?  I ask because I'm wanting to use this as a method of intercommunication across the AppDomain boundaries.   Does this method simply create an instance in the local heap or does it exist across the boundary?

Comment: CreateInstanceAndUnwrap creates an instance in the target domain (across the boundary) and provides a TransparentProxy reference to it in the calling domain.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's exactly what I needed. If I pass a shared type across by way of an interface method is it serialized or is it passed by reference.  I'm new to AppDomains if you can't tell.

Comment: It depends...if your parameter type is MarshalByRef or if your method uses the ref keyword for the parameter, it's by reference. Otherwise it's serialized with BinaryFormatter. Random link: http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2008/05/10/passing-parameters-in-.net-remoting.aspx (see the bottom)